# When companies ask for "Location" in job applications what do they want to know?

Tags: job-search

If companies ask for 'Location' in online job application forms, what do they want to know? The legal headquarters of the company I am working for? The place I spend most of my time? The place where I have my legal residence? My country of origin? Why does it even matter?

Comment: what part of the application? The work history part? or the personal information part? or some other part?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep personal information

Comment: They want to know where you live.  But it would also be helpful if you told them what sort of commute you would accept, either by distance or time.

Answer (score 0):

When asking for location they mean the place where you live.

It matters because hiring a non local means a lot of logistic effort, even interviewing one accrues expenses if they are paying transport etc,.

Comment: Well, it won't help them that I live 9 months of the year in A if they interview is during the remaining three months when I'm in B. Also, are interview costs really so important for this to be the first question they ask?

Comment: Also cost of living (and current salary figure) is proportional to the city where you live. This and possibly the cost of your relocation (or a perk to pay for it)